# Update joined query with TClientDataset

Tags: sql-server, delphi, tclientdataset

I have a SQL Server DB with these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [key1] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [key2] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [data1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [data2] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_2](
    [key1] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [key2] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [data3] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [data4] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a query that pulls in all the fields:

```
select 
  t1.key1, t1.key2, t1.data1, t1.data2,
  t2.key1, t2.key2, t2.data3, t2.data4
from Table_1 t1 join Table_2 t2 on 
  t1.key1 = t2.key1 and t1.key2 = t2.key2
```

I have a form with a `TDBGrid`, a `TADOConnection`, a `TADOQuery`, a `TDatasetProvider`, and a `TDataSource`. I have everything connected so that the grid displays the expected data from the query in design mode. The grid is not readonly, and all of the assorted datasets have `CanModify` true.

The form has a menu with an item which has the following `OnClick` method

```
procedure TCdsToy0Form.ApplyUpdates1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (dsCDStoGrid.DataSet as TClientDataSet).ApplyUpdates(0);
end;
```

When I use the grid to edit a value for a `data1` column and then click my Apply Updates menu item, I get this message:

```
Exception class EOleException with message 'Invalid column name 'key1_1''.
```

What am I doing wrong, or failing to do?

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: As I remember, `t1.key1, t1.key2` and `t2.key1, t2.key2` internally have the same names independently on table names. So to avoid this misunderstood you have to 1) name table fields respected to table name (`t1_key1, t2_key1` and so on for example) 2) more complex solution: rename fields in the query: `t1.key1 as as t1key1, t2.key1 as t2key1` for example. And use this aliases as SP parameters.

Answer (score 3):

When a ClientDataset is based on joined tables it may not be able to determine which columns/table to update. In this case you need to tell it how. See [this](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/5ds3interveningasupdatesareapplied_xml.html) article which explains what you need to do. Basically you may have to implement code in `OnGetTableName`.